# Replace namespace prefixes with scoped default namespaces using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xmlbeans

Can you share an XSLT with me which achieves following please?

Input:

```
<alfa data="abc" xmlns="http://test1.com/">
  <mus:beta xmlns:mus="http://test2.com">
    <mus:a>1234567897</mus:a>
    <mus:s>777666</mus:s>
  </mus:beta>
</alfa>
```

Output should be:

```
<alfa data="abc" xmlns="http://test1.com/">
  <beta xmlns="http://test2.com">
    <a>1234567897</a>
    <s>777666</s>
  </beta>
</alfa>
```

In fact; the input is generated with XmlBeans; I can not achieve the output with xmlbeans; So i will do a transform with xslt in mediation; however I need a xslt first :) XmlBeans solution is acceptable too. :)

For xmlbeans users; following does not work, fyi:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
 map.put("http://test1.com/",""); 
 map.put("http://test2.com/","");
 xo.setSaveSuggestedPrefixes(map);
```

Cheers,
Kaan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:mus="http://test2.com"
  exclude-result-prefixes="mus"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mus:*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="namespace-uri()}">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! Please note the syntax error: namespace="{namespace-uri(.)}".      For Java developers: Xalan does not give a correct transformation; However Saxon does.       
Stylus Studio works with this xsl as well. So I believe something is confusing with Xalan: A configuration or a bug; I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

If you explicitly add a namespace declaration to the document, XmlBeans will respect it.  You can add a new default namespace mid-document by using the [XmlCursor](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlCursor.html) APIs.  For example,

```
    XmlObject xobj = XmlObject.Factory.parse(
            "<a xmlns='testA'>\n" +
            "  <B:b xmlns:B='testB'>\n" +
            "    <B:x>12345</B:x>\n" +
            "  </B:b>\n" +
            "</a>");

    // Use xpath with namespace declaration to find <B:b> element.
    XmlObject bobj = xobj.selectPath(
            "declare namespace B='testB'" +
            ".//B:b")[0];

    XmlCursor cur = null;
    try
    {
        cur = bobj.newCursor();
        cur.removeAttribute(new QName("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "B"));
        cur.toNextToken();
        cur.insertNamespace("", "testB");
    }
    finally
    {
        cur.dispose();
    }

    System.out.println(xobj.xmlText());
```

Comment: Nice! Can the selectPath() step be skipped?

Comment: Yep, it can be skipped.  If you already have an XmlObject in hand, just use that.  I just used selectPath() to quickly grab the desired XmlObject.

Comment: Thanks. I actually needed the selectPath() query but with a **default** namespace, for which [I did not find the proper syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19792820/1864054). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I've answered the linked question, but in short: use `declare namespace B=''` in the xpath expression.